# request()->validate() does not work the second time around n laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I have a method to store and validate data from POST request, the first method works fine and validated successfully.

```
public function saveClientInfo(){
        ClientInfo::create($this->validateClientInfo());
    }
    public function validateClientInfo(){
        return request()->validate([
            'code' => 'required',
            're' => ['required','unique:client_infos'],
            'name' => 'required',
            'contact' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'property' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required'
        ]);
    }
```

Here in this second method with the same structure for saving and validating the requests, it doesn't work I'm very intrigue as to why.

```
public function loanStatus(){
        PaymentInfo::create($this->validatePay());
    }
    public function validatePay(){
        return request()->validate([
            'payment_type' => 'required',
            'terms' => 'required',
            'amount_due' => 'required',
            'from' => 'required',
            'to' => 'required'
        ]);
    }
```

By the way they're in the same controller so I dont get nauseous trying to figure out what is the difference of both as to where I went wrong.

**NOTE:**

> the error it gives is Route GET is not Supported suggested Method
> POSTS some sort of like this,

that's why it's confusing enough already I checked the form and routes and I used post so why this error is showing so I figure it must be the request validate part.

Blade File

```
 <form action="/proceed/loan-status" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="re" value="{{ $re }}">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="payment-type" placeholder="Payment Type...">
                        @if($errors->has('payment_type'))
                              <p class="alert text-danger">{{ $errors->first('payment_type') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="terms" placeholder="Terms...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <input type="number" min="2" max="" step="any" class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount Due...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from" placeholder="From...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" placeholder="To...">
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Save</button>
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cancel</a>
        </div>
        </form>
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/proceed/loan-status', 'ClientInfoController@loanStatus');
```

Comment: show route for that

Comment: also post blade template where you posting this

Comment: @JohnLobo here is the route Route::post('/proceed/payment-info', 'ClientInfoController@paymentInfo');

Answer (score 1):

If your Laravel version is 8, change the route sintax

```
Route::post('/proceed/loan-status', ClientInfoController::class,'loanStatus')->name('proceed.loan-status');
```

and in the blade form change the action to

```
<form action="{{ route('proceed.loan-status') }}" method="POST">
```

Also, I suggest you use validation request like Laravel doc, it's a better coded controller and adjusted to patterns. Changing that, you must have something like

```
public function loanStatus(StorePaymentInfoRequest $request){
  PaymentInfo::create($request->validated());
}
```

and in the StorePaymentInfoRequest

```
/**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'payment_type' => 'required',
            'terms' => 'required',
            'amount_due' => 'required',
            'from' => 'required',
            'to' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I followed your answer starting from route changes to request creation and now I get a 403 this action is unauthorized

Comment: In the request validation class public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

Comment: yup I updated it to true and now I'm back with the same errror, Get method is not supported for this route supported method POST

Comment: also the blade I'm redirecting it to also has another form to submit with a slug not id from previous form to be submitted and validated for saving

Answer (score 1):

Please use the laravel's request validation.

php artisan make:request FormRequest

It will generate a file that you can use.

https://medium.com/@kamerk22/the-smart-way-to-handle-request-validation-in-laravel-5e8886279271

This Article is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

The error look like you have defined `post route` in `web.php` but you are requesting form method is `GET` or vice versa .So it throwing error

So you need to change form method to post to support that

```
<form method="POST" >
```

Or if you still need get request in form method then you need to update routes form post to get

Comment: I have POST method in my form and routes as well

Comment: Route::post('/proceed/payment-info', 'ClientInfoController@paymentInfo');

Comment: @ErrolBoneo. show full blade code ,route  as well

Comment: as your method in controller paymentInfo but your showed different method in your post for validation

Comment: @ErrolBoneo. form action pointing to action="/proceed/loan-status" but your route is different proceed/payment-info

Comment: yeah try to refresh again I updated it aleady

Comment: i saw but action is /proceed/loan-status but you provided route Route::post('/proceed/payment-info' is this but in your question method doesnt match

Comment: here you go Route::post('/proceed/loan-status', 'ClientInfoController@loanStatus');

Comment: the issue is you are not showing error in your blade template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233213/discussion-between-errol-boneo-and-john-lobo).

Answer (score 0):

in your Route put your code like this
ROUTE::POST('/VARRIBALE NAME', [CONTROLLER NAME::CLASS, 'FUNCTIONNAME']->NAME('VARRIBALE NAME.FUNCTIONNAME);